# Infinite, noise-generated tile map in Cocos2d/ios?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have been working for weeks on a game concept in java, and have decided it will be best to implement the game in iOS, primarily for iPad. I wrote everything myself in java and am now researching what I need to do to convert.

I haven't decided on a framework but am eying Cocos2d. However, I've not been able to find any information on a recommended method to make an infinite map. Infinite side-scrolling yes, but mine is is "infinite" in all directions.

Currently, I generate "chunks" of 16x16 tiles that are assigned biome/type info by a perlin/simplex noise generator. I wrote custom code that loads/unloads each chunk of tiles as you move. You may move in all directions.

Is this possible with the Cocos2d library? Or will I need to re-write my special rendering/map movement code in Objective-c?